# If else statement with try except block

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, try-except

I have a `try/except` code block that I want to modify with and `if/else` statement that will execute parts of the code and skip over others.

This is the logic stub I have right now:

```
if arg1 == 'None':
    do something
else:
    do something else

try:
    execute main code
except:
    update failed status

execute_seperate_function(arg)
```

What I want to do is if the code goes into the first `if statement`, then run the `try/except` and the last function as is. However, if it goes into the `else statement` I would like to run the `try` code as is, but skip executing the `except` and last function.

Is there a good way to do this instead of putting everything inside `if/else` statements and make the code really messy? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I can't help but think the exact nature of all the elided code would affect how you choose to structure it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could make it a function like the one below with a flag argument which determines if

```
def task(flag):
    if (flag == True):
        try:
            execute main code
        except:
            update failed status
        execute_seperate_function(arg)
    else:
        execute main code

if arg1 == 'None':
    task(True)
else:
    task(False)
```

Is that substantially neater? Depends on what `do something` is I suppose.

Comment: [The Python developers would mostly disagree.](https://grokbase.com/t/python/python-list/118s5jgxz3/ot-ish-design-principles-no-bool-arguments)

Comment: `execute main code` is repeated? ` Really?  What if it were 1000 lines of code?  `If (flag == True)` is not very Pythonic.

Comment: FWIW, the last `if-else` can further be eliminated by simply calling `task(arg1 == "None")`.

Answer (score 1):

To some extent, this may be achieved by splitting your logic across functions:

```
def do_something():
    try:
        execute_main_code()
    except Exception:
        update_failed_status()
    execute_separate_function(arg)


def do_something_else():
    execute_main_code()


def execute_main_code():
    pass


def update_failed_status():
    pass


def execute_separate_function(arg):
    pass


if arg1 == "None":
    do_something()
else:
    do_something_else()
```

Answer (score 1):

First, take what you consider as 'execute main code' and put in a function, which we can arbitrarily call `main':

```
def main:
    execute main code

if arg1 == 'None':
    try:
        main() # execute main code
    except Exception:
        update failed status
    execute_seperate_function(arg) # called whether there was an exception or not
else:
    main() # just exec main code without try block
```